Show data in edit field using laravel inertia and tagify from metronic8
I am trying to show the data of a field "work_places" in edit form, this filed is Tagify and I store the value in json filed.
this is how the data is stored in the database cell after making json_encode:
["test1","test2", "test3"]
and that's how I try to show the value in the edit form:
                    <div class="col-lg-8">
                        <label class="fs-6 form-label fw-bolder text-dark">Work Places</label>
                        <input class="form-control" id="work_places"/>
                        <div v-if="form.errors.work_places" v-text="form.errors.work_places" class="text-danger text-xs mt-1"></div>
                    </div>

<script setup>
import { useForm } from "@inertiajs/inertia-vue3";
import {onMounted, useAttrs} from "vue";

const attrs = useAttrs();

let props = defineProps({
    jobs_list: Object,
});


let form = useForm({
    name: props.jobs_list.name,
    work_places: JSON.parse(props.jobs_list.work_places),
    is_active: props.jobs_list.is_active,
});


let submit = () => {
    form.put('/constants/jobs-list/' + props.jobs_list.id);
}
onMounted(() => {
    var workPlacesInput = document.querySelector("#work_places");
    new Tagify(workPlacesInput, {
        whitelist: form.work_places.map(wp => ({ value: wp })),
    });
    workPlacesInput.addEventListener('change', (e) => {
        form.work_places = JSON.parse(e.target.value).map(tag => tag.value);
    });

});
</script>

but it does not work for me.
also I tried different ways to parse map the value, like:
work_places: JSON.parse(props.jobs_list.work_places).map(place => ({ value: place })),

whitelist: form.work_places.map(wp => wp.value),


and it still not working.

i solve it like this:
1- set the value attribute and bind it to variable: :value="initialValue"
<div class="col-lg-8">
                        <label class="fs-6 form-label fw-bolder text-dark">أماكن العمل</label>
                        <input class="form-control" :value="initialValue" id="work_places"/>
                        <div v-if="form.errors.work_places" v-text="form.errors.work_places" class="text-danger text-xs mt-1"></div>
                    </div>

let form = useForm({
    name: props.jobs_list.name,
    work_places: [],
    is_active: props.jobs_list.is_active,
});


// set the vale of the tagify input
let initialValue = ref(props.jobs_list.work_places ? JSON.parse(props.jobs_list.work_places) : '');

onMounted(() => {
    var workPlacesInput = document.querySelector("#work_places");
    new Tagify(workPlacesInput);

    // to handle the value before save it
    workPlacesInput.addEventListener('change', (e) => {
        form.work_places = JSON.parse(e.target.value).map(tag => tag.value);
    });
});


and don't forget to import {onMounted, ref} from "vue";
